# Installing Torch on Virtual Machine

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, virtual-machine, torch

I'm trying to install **Torch** on virtual machine which has OS as Ubuntu 14.04 desktop version.  I followed the instructions as given in [Getting started with Torch](http://torch.ch/docs/getting-started.html#_). There was no problem in cloning the torch folder from github. In the second step which install dependencies show the following error:

```
make[1]: *** [libs] Error 1

make[1]: Leaving directory `/tmp/OpenBLAS/kernel'

make: *** [libs] Error 1

Error. OpenBLAS could not be compiled
```

Please help me to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu is missing a `gfortran-dev` package:

```
sudo apt-get install gfortran-4.9
```

Should solve your issue.
[Reference](https://github.com/xianyi/OpenBLAS/issues/1020)